# Splitting an area on the globe given by 4 Latitude Longitude coordinates into an equidistant grid?

Tags: java, gps, geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

So I'm working on a final project in Java language, this project has a server side (which is under my responsibility) and a GUI client (which is under someones else responsibility).

As a server I constantly get GPS coordination (as latitude longitude) from android clients and I need to reply with their equivalent location on a pre-allocated grid.

The grid is set by 4 LatLng coords sent to me by the GUI client and the amount of grid lines to be divided by. E.g. I get (35.000,35.000),(35.000,36.000),(36.000,36.000),(36.000,35.000) and 40x40.

The current method I use is by calculating the distance in radian degrees for the latitude distance of the area and the longitude distance separately, and then I divide it by 40 (like in the example given), each quotient is my "click", a single unit of distance I use later on.

When I receive a new coordinate I divide it by my "click" and do a Math.floor, the quotient of this operation is the location on the grid.
But something is wrong, my calculation are apparently incorrect, as the GUI client disagrees with me (usually by 1 grid north/south and 1 grid west/east, he simply takes the map (e.g. google-map) and manipulates it as a picture simply splitting a rectangular area.
What am I doing wrong? is there a better way to discretize the area given by this setup?

Things I've already check: 1. This is not some sort of float underflow, I used BigDecimal and [SimpleLatLng](https://github.com/JavadocMD/simplelatlng).

2. The GUI client agrees with me on locations closer to the relative 0x0 grid block, so it's not the usual off-by-one mistake.

EDIT: I've managed to work out most of the error, I still have some error which I don't know what part of the code can be responsible.

EDIT 2: The problem seems to be solved, the issue was not getting the correct bearing in the first place and just assuming the grid was north bound, the correct code is attached:

Comment: Splitting in a equidistance grid is complex, it would need a coordinate transformation. Much easier, depending on the applictaion is to split by  degrees. Then it is very easy to finde the correct grid cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to answer myself after exploring and playing with the code.
This is the final implementation of this solution as used in our projects code.
You can use it freely and hopefully it will help others in the future:

```
import com.javadocmd.simplelatlng.LatLng;
import com.javadocmd.simplelatlng.LatLngTool;
import com.javadocmd.simplelatlng.util.LengthUnit;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class GridMap {
private double lat_rad;
private double lng_rad;
private Polygon grid;
private double factor = 100000;
private List<LatLng> bounds = new LinkedList<>();

public GridMap(int lat_bin, int lng_bin, List<Double> coords) {
    // coords should be (y_bot, x_bot;,y_up, x_bot;y_up, x_up;y_bot, x_up)
    grid = new Polygon();
    for (int i = 0; i < coords.size(); i += 2) {
        int nx = (int) Math.floor(factor * coords.get(i));
        int ny = (int) Math.floor(factor * coords.get(i + 1));
        grid.addPoint(nx, ny);
        bounds.add(new LatLng(coords.get(i), coords.get(i + 1)));
    }
    lat_rad = LatLngTool.distance(bounds.get(0), bounds.get(1), LengthUnit.METER) / (lat_bin);
    lng_rad = LatLngTool.distance(bounds.get(0), bounds.get(3), LengthUnit.METER) / (lng_bin);
}

public boolean inGrid(LatLng point) {
    int lat = (int) Math.floor(factor * point.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) Math.floor(factor * point.getLongitude());
    return grid.contains(lat, lng);
}

public Point toGrid(LatLng llp) {
    if (inGrid(llp)) {
        double lat = llp.getLatitude();
        double lng = llp.getLongitude();
        double rel_lat = bounds.get(0).getLatitude();
        double rel_lng = bounds.get(0).getLongitude();
        int ilat = (int) Math.floor(LatLngTool.distance(new LatLng(rel_lat, lng), bounds.get(0), LengthUnit.METER) / lat_rad);
        int ilng = (int) Math.floor(LatLngTool.distance(new LatLng(lat, rel_lng), bounds.get(0), LengthUnit.METER) / lng_rad);
        return new Point(ilat, ilng);
    }
    return new Point(-1, -1);
}

public LatLng toLatLng(Point gridLoc){
    double lat_dist = (gridLoc.getY() + 0.5) * lat_rad;
    double lng_dist = (gridLoc.getX() + 0.5) * lng_rad;
    double y_bearing = LatLngTool.initialBearing(bounds.get(0), bounds.get(1));
    double x_bearing = LatLngTool.initialBearing(bounds.get(1), bounds.get(2));
    LatLng startLatLng = new LatLng(bounds.get(0).getLatitude(), bounds.get(0).getLongitude());
    LatLng lat_llp = LatLngTool.travel(startLatLng, y_bearing, lat_dist, LengthUnit.METER);
    return LatLngTool.travel(lat_llp, x_bearing, lng_dist, LengthUnit.METER);
}
}
```